# SQL Trigger columns don't match

Tags: sql, triggers

```
{`CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[Transport_Trigger]
ON [dbo].[Transporter$]
FOR INSERT
AS
BEGIN
   INSERT INTO [dbo].[Transporter]
   (
    [Transporter],
    [Company],
    [id]
    
    )
   SELECT
    [Transporter],
    [Company],
    [id], 'I', 'I'
   FROM INSERTED Where [dbo].[Transporter$].[Company] <> [dbo].[Transporter].[Company];
  
END;`
```

}
Hi,
I have created this trigger if the company name docent match it will insert the data on to the other table when data is inserted to the primary table. But I am getting the below error. filed on both the tables are exactly the same, please help. error "*Msg 121, Level 15, State 1, Procedure Transport_Trigger, Line 13
The select list for the INSERT statement contains more items than the insert list. The number of SELECT values must match the number of INSERT columns.*"

Comment: Help us help you - share the definitions of your table

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (The above code is product specific.)

Comment: You try do insert 5 values into 3 columns...

Comment: TABLE [dbo].[Transporter$](
 [Transporter] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
 [Company] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
 [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]                                                                                                               TABLE [dbo].[Transporter](
 [Transporter] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
 [Company] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
 [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]